# Multiple Threads in a JVM

Tags: java, hadoop, jvm

I have 1 GB of memory allocated to a JVM . I want to generate multiple threads executing some functionality.How can I know how much of JVM space is taken up by the single thread.

Comment: What do you mean by "JVM space"? Java Heap, thread stacks, virtual address space or what?

Comment: Thanks Apangin !I was referring to Java Heap and Thread stack.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your JVM. For [HotSpot](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html), there's a `java` application launcher VM option to set the size of the thread stack:

```
XX:ThreadStackSize=512
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle's JVM:

```
Thread t = new Thread(); //to simulate your thread

com.sun.managment.ThreadMXBean tmxb =   ManagmentFactory.getThreadMXBean();

long mem = tmxb.getThreadAllocatedBytes(t.getId());
```